Could not find com.novoda:bintray-release:0.4.0
enter image description here
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AndroidV2'.

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.novoda:bintray-release:0.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.4.0/bintray-release-0.4.0.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.4.0/bintray-release-0.4.0.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.4.0/bintray-release-0.4.0.pom
Required by:
project :

Possible solution:

Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html


That used to be published via JCenter, which was discontinued a couple of months ago.

is there a solution for this problem ?

Do you even need the library anymore? If not, remove it. If you do, contact Bintray and ask them for recommendations.

this my script below in build.gradle(Project level) works with the current latest **com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.2**
buildscript {
    repositories {
            google() 
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.scijava.org/content/repositories/public' }
  
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.1'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
           google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/novoda/maven" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

